# MySQL - merging table rows (group by won't work)

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm having some trouble with finalizing my MySQL query. Imagine that i combine the tables tickets, invoice line and users. Each ticket has one or more invoice lines and each user can have one or more tickets.

I'm trying to create a query which I can use to create the name badges. For this badge I need to know the name and the items the person registered for.

I created the following MySQL query

```
SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, il.invID, il.name, 
CASE 
  WHEN il.name = 'Conference Dinner' 
  THEN 'Diner'
END AS 'conference_dinner',

CASE 
  WHEN il.name = 'Regular Conference Fee' THEN 'Conference'
  WHEN il.name = 'Conference Fee for Phd. Students'  THEN 'Conference'
END AS 'conference',

CASE
  WHEN il.name = 'Pre-Conference Fee' THEN 'Pre-Conference'
END AS 'pre_conference',

FROM invoice_line il, events_tickets et, users u
WHERE il.invID = et.invID
AND et.userID = u.ID
```

The query is almost fine, however it produces for a user with three invoice lines (= three items) three lines in the table, and I'd like these three lines to merge to one line. A Group By on the users ID will result in one line, but than the case created columns won't be merged into the one line, only one of them is displayed.

I might have used the wrong way of doing this. But It should result in an table like this:

```
firstName | lastName | conference_diner | conference | pre_conference |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
John      | Doe      | Diner            | Conference |                |
Jane      | Norman   |                  | Conference | Pre-Conference | 
Martijn   | Thomas   |                  | Conference |                |
Pete      | Johns    |                  |            | Pre-Conference |
```

Currently this results in:

```
firstName | lastName | conference_diner | conference | pre_conference |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
John      | Doe      | Diner            |            |                |
John      | Doe      |                  | Conference |                |
Jane      | Norman   |                  | Conference |                |
Jane      | Norman   |                  |            | Pre-Conference |  
Martijn   | Thomas   |                  | Conference |                |
Pete      | Johns    |                  |            | Pre-Conference |
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please include the source data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might try something along these lines:

```
SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, il.invID, il.name,
IF(SUM(il.name = 'Conference Dinner') > 0,
    'Diner', '') AS 'conference_dinner',
IF(SUM(il.name IN ('Regular Conference Fee',
                   'Conference Fee for Phd. Students')) > 0,
    'Conference', '') AS 'conference',
IF(SUM(il.name = 'Pre-Conference Fee') > 0,
    'Pre-Conference', '') AS 'pre_conference'
FROM invoice_line il, events_tickets et, users u
WHERE il.invID = et.invID
AND et.userID = u.ID
GROUP BY u.ID
```

A comparison in mysql results in a number, 0 for *false* and 1 for *true*. So you can simply sum those up to count the lines matching a given expression. In other words, all the lines from the join which belong to a single user are grouped, those matching a certain property are counted, and these counts will decide what to print as the aggregate value for that user in the resulting table.

Comment: Thnx MvG that did the trick! Going to remember the solution :)

Comment: Why is `IF(SUM(x IN (a,b,c)) > 0, y, '')` preferred to just `MAX(IF(x IN (a,b,c), y, ''))`?

Comment: @Dems: Mainly personal preference, I guess. One advantage is that the `IF` is executed after aggregation, not before, which might be *slightly* more efficient. On the other hand, `MAX` is in some SQL standard and the numeric interpretation of booleans isn't, as far as I know, so using `MAX` might be more portable. In case you want to print localized versions of `yes` or `no`, you'd have to use `MIN` in some locales, while the `SUM` stays as it is…

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

```
SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, et.invID,
CASE 
  WHEN il_d.name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Diner'
END AS 'conference_dinner',

CASE 
  WHEN il_c.name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Conference'
END AS 'conference',

CASE
  WHEN il_p.name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Pre-Conference'
END AS 'pre_conference'
FROM events_tickets et
INNER JOIN users u ON et.userID = u.ID
LEFT JOIN invoice_line il_d ON il_d.invID = et.invID AND il_d.name = 'Conference Dinner'
LEFT JOIN invoice_line il_c ON il_c.invID = et.invID AND il_c.name IN ('Regular Conference Fee', 'Conference Fee for Phd. Students')
LEFT JOIN invoice_line il_p ON il_p.invID = et.invID AND il_p.name = 'Pre-Conference Fee'
```

Comment: I do get the following error:
#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'FROM events_tickets et INNER JOIN users u ON et.userID = u.ID LEFT JOIN invoice_' at line 13

When i remove the comma after 'pre_conference' and only keep the firstName and lastName in the select part i get the following error:
'CASE WHEN il_d.name IS NULL THEN '' ELSE 'Diner' END AS 'conference_dinner', ' at line 2

Comment: sorry, rogue comment in there... fixed now.

Answer (score 1):

As you haven't included the source data, I'm going to make an assumption that each column in your final results relates to one row in your input data.

This means that you *do* wan to use a `GROUP BY`...

```
SELECT
  u.firstName, u.lastName, il.invID, il.name, 
  MAX(CASE
    WHEN il.name = 'Conference Dinner'                 THEN 'Diner'
  END) AS 'conference_dinner',
  MAX(CASE
    WHEN il.name = 'Regular Conference Fee'            THEN 'Conference'
    WHEN il.name = 'Conference Fee for Phd. Students'  THEN 'Conference'
  END) AS 'conference',    
  MAX(CASE
    WHEN il.name = 'Pre-Conference Fee'                THEN 'Pre-Conference'
  END) AS 'pre_conference'

FROM
  invoice_line il, events_tickets et, users u
WHERE
  il.invID = et.invID AND et.userID = u.ID
GROUP BY
  u.firstName, u.lastName
```

I have, however, had to remove `il.invID, il.name,` from the `SELECT`.  This is because I'm inferring that they can have different values.  In which case, which value do you want to show in the aggregated results?

**EDIT**:

This has an advantage over the multiple `LEFT JOIN` version in that it only scans the `invoice_line` talb eonce, not multiple times.  This *should* mean lower reads, potentially lower cpu, and generally lower execution time.

The down side is that it is marginally more complex, and less straight forward to extract all the individual `il.invID` and `il.name` values if they are needed.

Answer (score 0):

Add some self joins on the event_tickets table

```
SELECT u.firstName, u.lastName, il.invID, il.name, 
CASE 
  WHEN il.name = 'Conference Dinner' 
  THEN 'Diner'
END AS 'conference_dinner',

CASE 
  WHEN il.name = 'Regular Conference Fee' THEN 'Conference'
  WHEN il.name = 'Conference Fee for Phd. Students'  THEN 'Conference'
END AS 'conference',

CASE
  WHEN il.name = 'Pre-Conference Fee' THEN 'Pre-Conference'
END AS 'pre_conference',

FROM invoice_line il, events_tickets et1, events_tickets et2, event_tickets et3, users u
WHERE il.invID = et.invID
AND et1.userID = u.ID
AND et2.userID = u.ID
AND et3.userID = u.ID
```

but also include something in the join that makes sure you don't get dinner twice so for eample if et.name is the attribute that specifies 'Diner' vs 'Conferece' etc then you'll need

```
AND et1.name > et2.Name
AND et.name > et3.name
```

and possibly some null handling.